# sub-category with photos in magento2

Tags: magento2, category, category-listing, category-view

I would like to create a sub-category with photos on my site.
How could you do that?
As on the example pages and screenshot.

https://www.moebel.de/wohnen

https://www.home24.de/wohn-accessoires/
[image]
[image]

Comment: There is already an option to add photos in categories, you only have to get photos of sub categories in frontend

Comment: How do you mean that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I explained that correctly!

I found another sample page https://www.wayfair.com/

I have a navigation above With multiple categories

I press as an example

-Outdoor-

Now a page opens where all subcategories of outdoor are in it, With photos

Now I press on the category

-Outdoor & Patio Furniture-

Now a page opens where all subcategories of -Outdoor & Patio Furniture- are in it, With photos

Now I press on the category

-Patio Furniture Sets-

Now a page opens where all sgories of -Patio Conversation Sets- are in it, With photos.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]